# pycharm remote debugging unable to retrieve variables

Tags: pycharm, openstack, devstack

I just getting started to develop openstack.

when it comes to debuging program on my server where devstack is deployed, I congured remote debug options flowing docs on Pycharm's offcial site.

problem raised.

The Frames or call stack? display normally, but variables can't not be displayed and show message "**Unable to display frame variables**"

what i did just as below:

- mount remote system to local using sshfs
- setup pycharm remote debug options
- add pydevd to my code and connection had been made normally.

I even tried add both `/usr/bin` and virtualenv on server as remote interpreter, variables when debugging still can't be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem like you. Check the configurations of your PyCharm.

See here for the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742235/4151472

I hope it helps.