# Unable to display frame variables (PyCharm remote debugger)

Tags: pycharm, remote-debugging, gevent

**What's the problem?**

I set up in PyCharm (version 2016.1.4) remote-debugging using the remote interpreter (not Debug Server!) as described here: [jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/remote-debugging.html#5).

When I run in Debug mode the program stops at the break point as it should. But, in the Variables window the variables are not displayed. Instead I get the following Error:

> Unable to display frame variables

I guess this is the same problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239981/pycharm-remote-debugging-unable-to-retrieve-variables)

**What did I try?**

I found this [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/08/gevent-debug-support/) with a possible solution, but it doesn't work for me. Based on this solution, I modified my `helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py` file as follows:

From:

```
try:
    SUPPORT_GEVENT = os.getenv('GEVENT_SUPPORT', 'False') == 'True'
except:
    # Jython 2.1 doesn't accept that construct
    SUPPORT_GEVENT = False

# At the moment gevent supports Python >= 2.6 and Python >= 3.3
USE_LIB_COPY = SUPPORT_GEVENT and \
               ((not IS_PY3K and sys.version_info[1] >= 6) or
                (IS_PY3K and sys.version_info[1] >= 3))
```

To:

```
try:
    SUPPORT_GEVENT = os.getenv('GEVENT_SUPPORT', 'False') == 'True'
    try:
        import gevent
        SUPPORT_GEVENT = True
    except:
        SUPPORT_GEVENT = False
except:
    # Jython 2.1 doesn't accept that construct
    SUPPORT_GEVENT = False

# At the moment gevent supports Python >= 2.6 and Python >= 3.3
USE_LIB_COPY = SUPPORT_GEVENT and \
               ((not IS_PY3K and sys.version_info[1] >= 6) or
                (IS_PY3K and sys.version_info[1] >= 3))
```

but it still doesn't work. I still cannot see the variables.

Anybody any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In recent versions of PyCharm, the option has moved to the main settings dialog. You can enable it under Settings | Python Debugger | Gevent compatible debugging.

[Reference](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/08/gevent-debug-support/)