# How to fix “Unable to display frame variables” in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run in Debug mode of Pycharm, in the Variables window the variables are not displayed. It displays: `Unable to display frame variables`.

I tried the solutions:

1. [Unable to display frame variables (PyCharm remote debugger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728624/unable-to-display-frame-variables-pycharm-remote-debugger)
2. http://techqa.info/programming/question/39728624/Unable-to-display-frame-variables--PyCharm-remote-debugger-

But they didn't fix it. Any one can provide a perfect solution?

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Pycharm: 2017.2

Comment: In my case, I am working with very large dictionaries and lists. Maybe that could be the reason? Some kind of timeout?

Comment: I agree with that. But if I want to check the intermediate result， only add print command working?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Go to `File -> Settings -> Python Debbuger` and check the `Gevent compatible` option.